# Problem in browsing after turning raspberry pi into access point

Tags: access-point

I have turned my pi into access point using the relevant configuration given in raspberrypi.org site.
Now I can see pi as access point on my mobile and can get connected but still can not browse.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome -- What do you mean by "*can not browse*"? Does it mean there is no internet connectivity?

Comment: Yes , there is no internet connectivity.

Comment: Is the IP address of `wlan0` is `192.168.4.1`? Did you enable IP forwarding?

Comment: Yes I have enabled IP forwarding using this IP. I can see this IP in my network details.

Comment: Add these config files/command output to the question: `cat /etc/default/hostapd` - `cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` - `cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf` - `ifconfig` - `iwconfig` - `service hostapd status` - `cat /etc/sysctl.conf `

Comment: On the Raspberry Pi please execute this command: `ping google.com`. Do you get responses?